# C# Winforms: Resize and overlap a control over another on buttonclick (possibly with transition animation)

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, user-interface, controls

Let's say you have a form (in winform project) with 2 controls (control1 and control2) arranged in a menu/detail fashion, so that control1 is a menu (occuping the left portion of the form) and control2 represents the detail (occuping the right, bigger portion of our form).

Now, when I click a button I want the menu to disappear, overlapped by the detail control (which of course increases its size to the left), when the button is pressed again the operation must be reversed. It would be nice if this may be done with a short transition animation which shows the detail control progressively increasing its size to the left, covering the menu.

Of course one can do this messing around with Control.Location and Control.Size, and probably even acquire a transition animation with a thread which progressively increases the size while forcing some repaints, but I was wondering if there's a faster - better - cleaner way to reach my goal.

Comment: `faster - better - cleaner way to reach my goal` - Yes. forget winforms and use any of the current, better, much more scalable, customizable, hardware accelerated, vector-based, XAML-based technologies (such as WPF or WinRT XAML), all of which have built-in support for Animations and many other [interactivity features](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/). winforms is a really old technology that doesn't support anything and it's not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: Well, that's for sure. Unfortunately my application is written in Windows Forms. Is there any hint for such environment?

Comment: no, winforms doesn't have any animations feature. You will have to implement it yourself using a thread that modifies the controls' width or whatever.